Inverse of a Matrix using Gauss Jordan Elimination on Julia
I want to make an algorithm that uses the Gauss-Jordan method to compute the inverse of a Matrix. I am more familiar with Matlab so I wrote this Matlab algorithm first. It works fine but I cannot make it to work on Julia
function [Inv,P]=GJinv(A)
  format rat
  n=length(A);
  P=eye(n); 
  Inv=[A,eye(n)]; 
  for k=1:n
        
        [~,r] = max(abs(A(k:end,k)));
        r = n-(n-k+1)+r;    
        #αλλάζω γραμμές#
        Inv([k r],:) = Inv([r k],:);
        P([k r],:) = P([r k],:);
       
        Inv(k,:) = Inv(k,:) / Inv(k,k);
        for i=1:n
          if i~=k
            Inv(i,:)=Inv(i,:)-(Inv(i,k)*Inv(k,:)); 
          endif
        endfor
  endfor
  Inv=Inv(1:n,n+1:2*n);
endfunction

My work so far:
using LinearAlgebra
function GJinv(A)
    (n,b)=size(A)
    Inv=[A,I(n)] 
    for k=1:n
          
          local ma=maximum(abs.(A[k:n,k:k])) 
          local pos = findfirst( x -> x == ma, abs.(A[k:n,k:n]))
          local r=pos[1] ; local r= n-(n-k+1)+r 
          #αλλάζω γραμμές#
          Inv[[k, r],:] = Inv[[r, k],:]
          
          Inv[k,:] = Inv[k,:] / Inv[k,k]
          for i=1:n
            if i!=k
              Inv[i,:]=Inv[i,:]-(Inv[i,k]*Inv[k,:]) 
            end
          end
    end
    Inv=Inv[1:n,n+1:2*n]
    print(Inv)
end
#TEST
A=[2 2 3; 4 5 6; 1 2 4]
GJinv(A)    

I am getting the following error:
ERROR: LoadError: InexactError: Int64(1.25)
Stacktrace:
  [1] Int64
    @ .\float.jl:912 [inlined]
  [2] convert
    @ .\number.jl:7 [inlined]
  [3] setindex!
    @ .\array.jl:1024 [inlined]
  [4] macro expansion
    @ .\multidimensional.jl:960 [inlined]
  [5] macro expansion
    @ .\cartesian.jl:64 [inlined]
  [6] _unsafe_setindex!(::IndexLinear, ::Matrix{Int64}, ::Vector{Float64}, ::Int64, ::Base.Slice{Base.OneTo{Int64}})
    @ Base .\multidimensional.jl:955
  [7] _setindex!
    @ .\multidimensional.jl:944 [inlined]
  [8] setindex!
    @ .\abstractarray.jl:1396 [inlined]
  [9] GJinv(A::Matrix{Int64})
    @\GJinv.jl:13
 [10] top-level scope
    @\GJinv.jl:24
in expression starting at @\GJinv.jl:24

Any help will be appreciated.

I can add coments on the code if needed but from a mathematical aspect it is correct

I don't know Matlab, but line 4 Inv = [A, I(n)] looks strange for me. This line makes a vector of two matrices: A and I(n). If you wanted to "append" I(n) to A, you need concatenation [A; I(n)] (vertical, 6×3 result for the test) or [A I(n)] (horizontal, 3×6 result for the test).

@StepanZakharov in MATLAB the coma and the colon mostly just separate if you concatenate a row or a column. There is vector of two matrices, unless you use cell arrays. MATLAB square bracket objects are always matrices

What I wanted to do was create the augmented Matrix. I will replace it with [A I(n)] and update the error

Your remaining error is you are making A be a Matrix{Int} rather than a Matrix{Float64}. You want A=Float64[2 2 3; 4 5 6; 1 2 4] (or alternatively  A=[2.0 2.0 3.0; 4.0 5.0 6.0; 1.0 2.0 4.0])

You were bitten by two problems of the syntax of MATLAB not being quite the same as Julia's syntax.
First, if you declare a matrix with all integer values in Julia the matrix will have an element type of Int, which will give you problems later when you divide, since in Julia the return type of
/(x::Int, y::Int)::Float64

is floating point
x / y

which you cannot then assign back to an Int matrix element. Second, as mentioned above by S Zakharov,
[A, I(n)]

will give you a Vector of Matrix in Julia, but you want the horizontal (hcat) matrix formed from two matrices.
So consider this correction (I fixed the syntax but did not change your algebra afaik):
using LinearAlgebra

function GJinv(squaremat)
    n, b = size(squaremat)
    @assert n == b # number of rows must == number of cols
    A = float.(squaremat)
    Inv = hcat(A, I(n))
    for k = 1:n
        ma = maximum(abs.(A[k:n,k:k])) 
        r = k + findfirst( x -> x == ma, abs.(A[k:n,k:n]))[1] - 1
        #αλλάζω γραμμές#
        Inv[[k, r],:] = Inv[[r, k],:]
        Inv[k,:] = Inv[k,:] / Inv[k,k]
        for i=1:n
            if i!=k
                Inv[i,:]=Inv[i,:]-(Inv[i,k]*Inv[k,:]) 
            end
        end
    end
    Inv = round.(Inv[1:n,n+1:2*n], digits = 6) # rounding makes it print better
    print(Inv)
end

 #TEST
 A=[2 2 3; 4 5 6; 1 2 4]

 GJinv(A)  # [1.6 -0.4 -0.6; -2.0 1.0 0.0; 0.6 -0.4 0.4] 

